# How to set up my notebook as a VPN service?

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a friend in Turkey who is being bothered by the DNS based banning of Twitter. Soon this is going to be done on IP level and already it seems like Google DNS is not reachable anymore. This got me thinking how it would be possible to make my computer available as a VPN server.

- I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64bit.
- My IP is dynamic but very stable for days - but it will change every time I reset my router.
- My router is only very moderately configurable.

I found two settings in my router configuration area that I am wondering whether they are relevant to this matter: "PPPoE Pass Through" can be enabled and "Port Forwarding" can be configured.

(Is "[mesh network](http://prism-break.org/en/categories/gnu-linux/#mesh-networks)" the central keyword here?)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried openvpn-as

https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as-sw/113.html?osfamily=Ubuntu

its free for 2 users

if he uses windows or mac

viscosity is a good openvpn client

http://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity/

or the openvpn option in the network-manager in ubuntu/Linux

another option is to use SSH Tunneling

Windows
http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/

Linux
http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: thanks (+1) - I will have a closer look at your suggestions